# AppleScript: set Safari tab to specific index

Tags: applescript, safari

I have an AppleScript which search for tab and run a JS in the selected tab,
It's work because of this :

```
set current tab of w to t
        set index of w to 1
```

but I would like to improve the code so I can refer the tab, at the moment as you can see I'm only referring the window ID and it's ok when I know the tab number
but how can I also refer the tab?

```
do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('myJShere')[0].click();" in tab tab 1 of window id theWindowID
```

I tried ***set theTabNumber to (id of t as string)*** but that doesn't work

t in my current example, return item 3 of {tab 1 of window id 6615 of application "Safari", tab 2 of window id 6615 of application "Safari", tab 3 of window id 6615 of application "Safari", tab 4 of window id 6615 of application "Safari"}

I tried :

```
set theTabNumber to item 1 of t
return theTabNumber
```

but this return

```
tab 3 of window id 6615 of application "Safari"
```

I suppose I could use text delimiting but that doesn't seems right

full script

```
set theTABID to 0
set searchpat to "Facebook"

tell application "Safari"
    set winlist to every window
    set winmatchlist to {}
    set tabmatchlist to {}
    set tabnamematchlist to {}
    repeat with win in winlist
        set ok to true
        try
            set tablist to every tab of win
        on error errmsg
            --display dialog name of win as string
            set ok to false
        end try
        if ok then
            repeat with t in tablist
                if searchpat is in (name of t as string) then
                    set end of winmatchlist to win
                    set end of tabmatchlist to t
                    set end of tabnamematchlist to (id of win as string) & "." & 1 & ".  " & (name of t as string)
                    set theTABID to (id of win as string)
                    ##return (index of t as string)
                    --display dialog name of t as string
                else if searchpat is in (URL of t as string) then
                    set end of winmatchlist to win
                    set end of tabmatchlist to t
                    set end of tabnamematchlist to (id of win as string) & "." & 1 & ".  " & (URL of t as string)
                    --display dialog name of t as string
                end if
            end repeat
        end if
    end repeat
    
    set w to item 1 of winmatchlist
    set t to item 1 of tabmatchlist
    
    set current tab of w to t
    set index of w to 1
    
end tell
 

if theTABID = 0 then
    
    
    set searchpat to "Twitter"
    ##set searchpat to "Case Management"
    tell application "Safari"
        set winlist to every window
        set winmatchlist to {}
        set tabmatchlist to {}
        set tabnamematchlist to {}
        repeat with win in winlist
            set ok to true
            try
                set tablist to every tab of win
            on error errmsg
                --display dialog name of win as string
                set ok to false
            end try
            if ok then
                repeat with t in tablist
                    if searchpat is in (name of t as string) then
                        set end of winmatchlist to win
                        set end of tabmatchlist to t
                        set end of tabnamematchlist to (id of win as string) & "." & 1 & ".  " & (name of t as string)
                        set theTABID to (id of win as string)
                        ##return (index of t as string)
                        --display dialog name of t as string
                    else if searchpat is in (URL of t as string) then
                        set end of winmatchlist to win
                        set end of tabmatchlist to t
                        set end of tabnamematchlist to (id of win as string) & "." & 1 & ".  " & (URL of t as string)
                        --display dialog name of t as string
                    end if
                end repeat
            end if
        end repeat
        
        set w to item 1 of winmatchlist
        set t to item 1 of tabmatchlist
        
        set current tab of w to t
        set index of w to 1
        
    end tell
end if

 
tell application "Safari"
    do JavaScript "document.getElementsByClassName('a8c37x1j ni8dbmo4 stjgntxs l9j0dhe7 ltmttdrg g0qnabr5 ')[0].click();" in current tab of window id theTABID
end tell
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are just trying to set the *value* of the *tab index* of `item 1 of t` to a *variable*, then is there some reason you can not just use `set theTabNumber to index of item 1 of t` instead of `set theTabNumber to item 1 of t`? -- This *code*, `set theTabNumber to index of item 1 of t` returns an *integer*, representing the r/o *index* of the *tab*, ordered left to right in that *window*.

That said, looking at the *code* in your OP, as coded, the `do JavaScript ...` *command* is going to execute regardless of the result of both *search strings*, which of course doesn't make any sense!

If you are testing for multiple *search strings*, it is more logical to execute different `do JavaScript ...` *commands* based on the *results*.

That said, as an exercise (hopefully not in futility) I decided to write a *handler* from scratch that does the following:

- Takes a *search string*.
- Searches the *name* of every *tab* of every *window* for the *search string*.
- If the *search string* is not found in the *name*, it searches the *URL* for it.
- If the *search string* is found, it brings the target *tab* and *window* to the front and returns a *list* with the *tab index* and *window id*.
- If the *search string* is not found, it returns a *list* with *missing value* for each *item* of the *list*, which can be used as the *flag* to execute a different *search string*.

For testing purposes, with multiple *windows* having multiple *tabs* with at least one set to "https://www.facebook.com" or "https://twitter.com" on different test runs of the *example* **AppleScript** *code*, and not logged into either, will search for "Facebook" or "Twitter" to bring their *windows* to the front and be the *current tab* to execute a `do JavaScript ...` *command* that will click the **Create New Account** button on **Facebook** or the **Sign up** button on **Twitter**.

**Note:** The *code* that brings the target *window* to the front and sets the target *tab* to the *current tab* can be commented out and use what's returned from the *handler* to target the *tab* by its *index* and the *window* by its *id* so it can be done in the background if wanted.

*Example* **AppleScript** *code*:

```applescript
findTabContainingSearchString("Facebook")
if result does not contain missing value then
    tell application "Safari" to tell document 1 to do JavaScript ¬
        "document.getElementsByClassName('_42ft _4jy0 _6lti _4jy6 _4jy2 selected _51sy')[0].click();"
else
    findTabContainingSearchString("Twitter")
    if result does not contain missing value then
        tell application "Safari" to tell document 1 to do JavaScript ¬
            "document.getElementsByClassName('css-901oao r-1awozwy r-jwli3a r-6koalj r-18u37iz r-16y2uox r-1qd0xha r-a023e6 r-vw2c0b r-1777fci r-eljoum r-dnmrzs r-bcqeeo r-q4m81j r-qvutc0')[0].click();"
    end if
end if


on findTabContainingSearchString(searchString)
    tell application "Safari"
        set tabIndex to missing value
        set winID to missing value
        set winList to windows
        repeat with w in winList
            set tabList to (tabs of w whose name contains searchString)
            try
                set tabIndex to (get index of first item of tabList)
            end try
            if tabIndex is not missing value then
                set winID to id of w
                exit repeat
            else
                set tabList to (tabs of w whose URL contains searchString)
                try
                    set tabIndex to (get index of first item of tabList)
                end try
                if tabIndex is not missing value then
                    set winID to id of w
                    exit repeat
                end if
            end if
        end repeat
        if winID is not missing value then
            set current tab of window id winID to tab tabIndex of window id winID
            set index of window id winID to 1
        end if
        return tabIndex & winID
    end tell
end findTabContainingSearchString
```

---

**Alternate Methods**

If you have commented out the `if winID is not missing value then` *block* in the *handler* in order to execute the `do JavaScript ...` *command* in the background, change:

```applescript
tell application "Safari" to tell document 1 to do JavaScript ¬
```

To:

```applescript
set {tabIndex, winID} to result
tell application "Safari" to tell tab tabIndex of window id winID to do JavaScript ¬
```

Or use an even different approach:

```applescript
set {tabIndex, winID} to findTabContainingSearchString("Facebook")
if {tabIndex, winID} does not contain missing value then
tell application "Safari" to tell tab tabIndex of window id winID to do JavaScript ¬
```

Comment: Thank you that's great, I just wondering, if I want to do JavaScript inside all the matching tab,  would I just change "first Item" and add a repeat statement here: try
    set tabIndex to (get index of first item of tabList)
   end try

Comment: @Kevin, In your OP, as coded, you where not acting on multiple _tabs_ containing the same _search string_ if more than one was found, only acting on the first _tab_ returned. The _handler_ I wrote does the same thing. That said, any _code_ can be modified to do something differently, albeit it depends on what one is trying to do as to how easily the _code_ can be modified. I'd suggest you try modifying it to suite a different need of yours and if you get stuck somewhere, post a different question. Thanks.

Comment: @Kevin, In other words I believe this answer covers what you were doing and anything different should be a different question so as not to muddy up what's already been presented. This site works best with one question per question. I'll be more than glad to help where I can if you end up posting another question to cover something explicitly different then what was asked in your OP here.

Comment: Yes you right sorry, that is perfect anyway thanks again

Comment: I wrote a handler a while ago to filter Safari tabs by URL. While there's nothing I can add to this (excellent) answer, it prompted me to upload [**mine as a gist**](https://gist.github.com/ChristoferK/f055fa0f1514c3b686a6c3f0673d2f95), as I keep meaning to do a big GitHub update but haven't the time. The intention behind it was to eliminate any repeat loops and thus––in AppleScript terms––optimise the speed and efficiency, whilst still being able to operate over all windows and all tabs. In regular use for a while but let me know if it blips.

Comment: @CJK, That a nice _handler_ and I actually had something similar in mind to use, however, while I could separately get the _tab index_ from the returned reference I couldn't figure out how to separately get the _window id_ from it too, so I went the route I did.